# Google Maps API v3 - Add text to symbol

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following symbol code:

```
var lineSymbol = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  fillColor: 'red',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  scale: 20
};
```

Which is added to a polyline like so:

```
m[i] = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: f0,
  icons: [{
    icon: lineSymbol,
    offset: '50%'
  }],
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: 'red',
  strokeOpacity: 0.6,
  strokeWeight: 5
});
```

This results in the following, a red circle in the centre of each polyline:

[image: polyline example]

My question is, is it possible to have some text within the circle? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible yet. An alternative would be to add a [marker with a clickable info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) on the same spot where the symbol is.